# How to copy one key:value one block underneath and repeat this for each following blocks?

Tags: python, bash, loops, vim

I have a yaml file where i need to copy a key:value (when: var) to the task underneath and need to repeat that for each block.

How it looks like now:

```
- set_fact: something
- set_fact: var_a
- task: do the foo
  when: var_a
- task: do the goo

- set_fact: something
- set_fact: var_b
- task: do the fofo
  when: var_b
- task: do the gogp

- set_fact: something
- set_fact: var_c
- task: do the fooolo
  when: var_c
- task: do the gooolo
```

How i need it to look like:

```
- set_fact: something
- set_fact: var_a
- task: do the foo
  when: var_a
- task: do the goo
  when: var_a

- set_fact: something
- set_fact: var_b
- task: do the fofo
  when: var_b
- task: do the gogp
  when: var_b

- set_fact: something
- set_fact: var_c
- task: do the fooolo
  when: var_c
- task: do the gooolo
  when: var_c
```

From researching how to do this, i think a vim loop could do that but i have no clue how to do that.
In case anybody has any hints, i'd be very grateful.

Edit: What i tried.
With this i captured the values i needed. (the var_ values)

```
grep -e set_fact -B1 filterlist_playbook.yml|grep -e "^.*\:"|grep -v "set\_fact\:"|awk -F":" '{print $1}'
```

I tried this in two different ways.

1 first add the "when:" field and then copy/paste the var_ value
Adding the when: field was ok with sed. Pasting the right value sequentially... i do not find info how to do that, my colleagues also do not know.

2 copy/paste the "when: var_" value to the block underneath.
Again capturing the right value is ok with sed, pasting it sequentially leaves me scratching my head and googling into oblivion.

Note:
I will definitely select a working answer but its taking me time to try each one of them.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried it first with grep/sed/awk maybe its possible that way but i did not find how to paste the value one block underneath. Also i just managed to capture the values i want to copy/paste but did not see how to paste those values sequentially. 
I had a look into Python but i have no clue which module i should use, i do not find similar case examples.
With Vim itself i'm looking into how to do this but i do not find an example or similar case. The more i look at it the more i think whatever tool i choose i will have the same issue, how to paste the values sequentially.

Comment: _I tried it first_ : I suggest that you show the code you tried, so that we have something to discuss. Otherwise your question might be closed. BTW, your problem seems to be related to _Ansible_ (not sure, since I never used ansible). In this case I suggest that you add the _ansible_ tag. BTW, what is a _vim-loop_? Do you plan to implement it as a vim macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would do it in Vim:

```
:g/when/normal mzvip^[:'zt'>^M
```

with `^[` obtained with `<C-v><Esc>` and `^M` obtained with `<C-v><CR>`.

Breakdown:

- `:g/<pattern>/<command>` executes `<command>` on every line that matches `<pattern>`.
- `:normal xxx` executes normal commands from command-line mode.
- `mz` puts mark `'z` on the matched line.
- `vip` visually selects the current paragraph, placing mark `'>` on its last line.
- `<Esc>` leaves visual mode.
- `:'zt'>` copies line with mark `'z` below line with mark `'>`.
- `<CR>` executes that last command.

See `:help :global`, `:help :normal`, `:help mark-motions`, `:h :t`, and `:h :range`.

Note that, intuitively, using mark `'}` like this:

```
:g/when/t'}
```

looks like it would solve the problem neatly, but Vim puts mark `'}` on the first blank line after an actual paragraph, which doesn't help us since our anchor is the last line of the actual paragraph.

That is one of the reasons why the `vip` dance is necessary: we need a mark **on** the last line of the paragraph, not **after** it, and visually selecting the "inner paragraph" does just that with mark `'>`.

Comment: Thanks (et merci), this is really Vim advanced, wow it blows my mind that it looks like its possible to be done in one line only.

Comment: I tried this but it seems that its selecting one block and then adding the when to that same block. Whereas i need the ```when: value``` to be pasted to the block just underneath. I will play a bit more with it, as its quite close to what i need. I had a feeling that this query was going to go over my head, the complexity is a way over my level but that's how you learn i guess.

Comment: It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Ok Thank you, then its me doing something wrong, i'll try and bite a bit deeper into it but my teeth are still quite small.

Comment: My bad i didnt exactly simulate the data structure of my real script. So yes this works.

Comment: Very nice, somehow I still didn't know `:g`! In this case it can even be simplified to `:g/when:/normal yyjp`, if you just need to copy each found line under the line below. Feel free to add this option to your answer if you wish.

Comment: Yeah, I know `normal yyjp` would work with OP's exact sample but I felt like providing a more generic solution that would work regardless of the number of lines after `when`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` you can do this:

```bash
awk -F ': ' '
$1 ~ / when$/ {var = $0}
NR > 1 {print prev}
!NF && prev ~ /^- task/ {print var}
{prev = $0}
END {
   print prev
   if (prev ~ /^- task/)
      print var
}' file
```

**Output:**

```bash
- set_fact: something
- set_fact: somethingelse
- task: do the foo
  when: var_a
- task: do the goo
  when: var_a

- set_fact: something
- set_fact: somethingelse
- task: do the fofo
  when: var_b
- task: do the gogp
  when: var_b

- set_fact: something
- set_fact: somethingelse
- task: do the fooolo
  when: var_c
- task: do the gooolo
  when: var_c
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply. I will have to study this first. Never seen such an elaborate awk command. I know awk is also a programming language but wow. I will come back on this asap i have understood how it works.

Comment: Yes, this is working. The Vim one liner seduced me although i think, AWK is probably more powerful.

Comment: Sure thing. It is your prerogative to pick whatever answer works best for you. One caveat I have noticed with `vim` answer is that if `when: var_a`  is already there in one of the blocks after last `task` line then `vim` solution will insert 2 more ` when: var_a` instead of ignoring it.

Answer (score 1):

In vim you could do this:

- `qq` start recording a macro called `q`
- `/when:`<kbd>Enter</kbd> find the next occurrence of `when:`
- `yy` yank the current line
- `j` move the cursor down
- `p` paste the line underneath
- `q` terminate the macro recording

At this point you can call the macro as many times as you need typing `@q`.

You may also get to know in advance how many times you need to perform this finding the occurrences of `when:` with `:%s/when://ng`, which will print out something like `3 matches on 3 lines`. Then you may just type e.g. `3@q` to call the macro 3 times.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i stumbled so many times into this macro recording by pressing qq by mistake and never took time to find out what it was. It looks like the easiest/fastest to understand solution. This is an answer at my level. I really need to deepdive into vim but also awk and sed as they look very powerful.

Comment: I was trying this out and it copies the first variable to every block underneath whilst i need the variable from each block to be pasted in the next task of the same block. I'm still grateful i learned something really useful. Its probably not possible to do with the macro function since it can only do the same action over and over.

Comment: Please ignore my above comment, since this solution DOES work. My data structure in the example was not identical to my real data, so my bad.

Answer (score 1):

If `ed` is available/acceptable.

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/^[[:space:]]\{1,\}when: var_.*/t.1' ,p Q | ed -s file.yaml
```

---

If the output is correct, and *in-place* editing is needed, change

```
,p Q
```

to

```
w q
```

I only have GNU `ed` at hand.

---

- `g`

  Globally substitute for all non-overlapping instances of the RE rather than just the first one. If both g and count are specified, the results are unspecified.
- (1,$)`g`/RE/command list
- (.,.)`t`address

  The `t` command shall be equivalent to the `m` command, except that a copy of the addressed lines shall be placed after address address (which can be 0); the current line number shall be set to the address of the last line added.
- `.`

  The period character ( `.` ) shall address the current line.
- The positive decimal number n shall address the nth line of the edit buffer.
- `,` or `%`

  Depending on the variant shall address the whole buffer.
  `,p` or `%p`
- (.,.)`p`

  The `p` command shall write to standard output the addressed lines; the current line number shall be set to the address of the last line written. The p command can be appended to any command other than e, E, f, q, Q, r, w, or !.
- `w`
  The `w` command shall write the addressed lines into the file named by the pathname file.
- `q`

  The q command shall cause ed to exit. If the buffer has changed since the last time the entire buffer was written, the user shall be warned, as described previously.
- `Q`

  The `Q` command shall cause ed to exit without checking whether changes have been made in the buffer since the last w command.
- `-s`
  Suppress the writing of byte counts by e, E, r, and w commands and of the '!' prompt after a !command.

---

See

- [POSIX ed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/ed.html)
- [GNU ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/)

---

In `vim` something like.

```
:g/^[[:space:]]*when: var_.*/t.1
```

Comment: Thanks, i know a tiny bit of SED, i didnt know ED exist. Any tool really doing the job would make my day since this is in reality a thousand lines long line where i will need to copy/paste about 35 times a different value.

Comment: Glad to be of help. jfyi `ed` predates `ex`, `vi`, `vim` and iirc `sed`, so yeah `ed` is pretty much prehistoric and ancient :-).

Answer (score 1):

To get the output you show from the input you show all you need is this, using any awk:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '{print $0 ORS $(NF-1) ORS}' file
- set_fact: something
- set_fact: var_a
- task: do the foo
  when: var_a
- task: do the goo
  when: var_a

- set_fact: something
- set_fact: var_b
- task: do the fofo
  when: var_b
- task: do the gogp
  when: var_b

- set_fact: something
- set_fact: var_c
- task: do the fooolo
  when: var_c
- task: do the gooolo
  when: var_c
```

or if your real input is more complicated than you've shown then, also using any awk:

```
$ awk '/when:/{w=$0} {print} /task:/ && w{print w; w=""}' file
- set_fact: something
- set_fact: var_a
- task: do the foo
  when: var_a
- task: do the goo
  when: var_a

- set_fact: something
- set_fact: var_b
- task: do the fofo
  when: var_b
- task: do the gogp
  when: var_b

- set_fact: something
- set_fact: var_c
- task: do the fooolo
  when: var_c
- task: do the gooolo
  when: var_c
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> {m,g}awk '
> BEGIN { _*= FS = "^" (OFS = "  when: ") (___="")
>
> } !_<NF ? (__=$_)*(NF=_) : ___<__ ? $!NF=__ RS $_ RS __ (__=___) : !_'
> ```

```
- set_fact: something
- set_fact: var_a
- task: do the foo
  when: var_a
- task: do the goo
  when: var_a

- set_fact: something
- set_fact: var_b
- task: do the fofo
  when: var_b
- task: do the gogp
  when: var_b

- set_fact: something
- set_fact: var_c
- task: do the fooolo
  when: var_c
- task: do the gooolo
  when: var_c
```

Comment: Thanks, yet another variation with mawk and gawk, had heard about them awk variations but never came across them.

Comment: @trainin99 : then i pity u, cuz once you've tried either, whatever `awk` that comes with `macos` feels like pure junk in comparison.